# Why is Vaadin ClickListener not firing on first click?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a table with several rows. When user click on a row the `ItemClickListener` enables a button:

```
testCaseTable.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {

        groupForm.tcDetailsButton.setEnabled(true);

        System.out.println("_________________");
        System.out.println("Item ID is: " + event.getItemId().toString());
        System.out.println("Item is: " + event.getItem().toString());
        System.out.println("Property ID is: " + event.getPropertyId().toString());
        System.out.println("_________________");
    }
});
```

The first time I click the button, nothing happens. The second time I click the button, it fires properly and opens the browser window.

```
tcDetailsButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3726094749730769327L;

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(EvoltwebUI.class);
        opener.setResource(new ExternalResource("google.com")); //url
        opener.setWindowName("_blank");
        opener.extend(tcDetailsButton); 

    }
});
```

It appears that if I click on 2 rows in my table, then click on the button, it opens 1 browser tab. If I click on 3 rows, then click on the button, it opens 2 browser tabs, 4 rows clicked = 3 tabs opened, etc.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by following Uladzimir Kordzik's suggestion above, but instead, I moved the declaration and instantiation of BrowserWindowOpener to the class level and extend the component to the opener before the click listener:

Class level declaration and instatiation:

`public BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(EvoltwebUI.class);`

Extend opener before click:

`opener.extend(tcDetailsButton);`

Click listener looks like this now:

```
tcDetailsButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3726094749730769327L;

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {             

            opener.setResource(new ExternalResource("google.com")); //url
            opener.setWindowName("_blank");                         

        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever buttonClick(ClickEvent event) is triggered, it adds a new copy of BrowserWindowOpener which receives the tcDetailsButton. But, except for the first time, tcDetailsButton  already have been received previous copy of BrowserWindowOpener. The situation is repeated with every click, doubling the number of windows each time.

I think, you should to initialize **BrowserWindowOpener** before the implementation of **buttonClick()** method, like this:

```
tcDetailsButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3726094749730769327L;

    final BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(EvoltwebUI.class);
    opener.extend(tcDetailsButton);

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        opener.setResource(new ExternalResource("google.com")); //url
        opener.setWindowName("_blank");   
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried changing my code to this but it would not compile.

Comment: Your comment lead me to the fix. I posted a new answer. Please see. Thanks again.

Comment: final statement is missing. thats why its not compiling.